# Referencing a specific argument in a variadic macro

Tags: c, macros, arguments, c99, argument-passing

There are a couple of questions and answers on SE dealing with counting the number of actual arguments passed to a variadic macro. There seems to be a canonical solution to this problem, whose variants repeat in the answers.

My question is, whether it is possible to refer to a specific argument in the list (in a safe way)? For example, if the macro is defined as:

```
#define MACRO(...) { some code involving __VA_ARGS__ }
```

is there a way for referrring to the 2nd argument in the list (e.g. `__VA_ARG_1__`), assuming that we know that it was actually passed? What if we do not know if it was passed?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
#define GET_SECOND(x, y, ...) (y)
#define MACRO(...) { some_code_using(GET_SECOND(__VA_ARGS__)); }
```

You'll get a suitable error message if you invoke `MACRO` with too few arguments.

Comment: OK, please see my update to the question: "What if we do not know if it was passed?" - is there a safe way to determine that?

Comment: @ysap: You get a compiler error. I think that's pretty safe, since it will stop you from shipping the program to your customers.

Comment: Well, I meant run-time safe... Maybe "safe" is not the best word here. I want to be able to determine whether ARGn is given before using it in the macro. AFAIR, you cannot `#ifdef` inside a macro, right?

Answer (score 0):

To get an arbitrary argument, the very frightening answer is contained here:

http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__list_8h.html

From my (admittedly non-expert) understanding of functional programming and programming language theory, it's doing recursion and pattern matching in the preprocessor, as is done in Haskell, OCaml, and the like, to peel off N elements, and then discards the suffix of the list, leaving you with the result.